# Why is a curve said to be regular iff its differential has full rank? Isn't this too strong of a condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^n$ which is parameterised via the map $t \mapsto (u(t),v(t))$, where $u,v$ are scalar functions. Even if both $u'(t)$ and $v'(t)$ never vanish $\forall t \in (a,b)$, they may still be constant multiples of each other, and hence the condition of full rank is violated. Yet, $\gamma$ is still somehow regular, as $\gamma'(t)$ never vanishes.

My understanding of linear algebra obviously has some deficiencies given the silliness of this question, but I do appreciate being set in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: The assumption is needed to be able to define the arc length parametrization and curvature of curve. But you can still define the arclength of a curve, the line integral of a vector field along the curve without this assumption . The fundamental theorem of line integrals also still holds.

Comment: All you need is a nonzero tangent (velocity) vector. You’re mistaken about full rank. You’re talking about a $2\times 1$ matrix: Full rank is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

An $n\times m$ matrix $A$ is called full rank if $\text{rank} (A) = \min\{m, n\}$. In your case $\gamma'(t) = (u'(t), v'(t))$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix, and thus is full rank if either $u'(t)$ or $v'(t)$ is non-zero.